# Redirect to php page based on form input

Tags: php, redirect

so i have a script which i need to redirect the user to a certain .php based on their entry. They will enter a user id like "user_123" the suffix will be extracted using strpos eg "123". So "123" should redirect to "123.php" etc

Here's the code i have for strpos part:

index.php

```
<html>
<form action="check.php" method="post">
User_number:<br>
<input type="email" name="usernum" value="" required><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

check.php

```
<?
$data = ['usernum'];
$request = substr($data, strpos($data, "_") + 1);
//added echo just for visual purposes
echo $request;
?>
```

1. How do i use the $request value to check against lets say an array, to redirect me to 123.php?
2. Create an if/else statement that will return an error message if no "_" is present in the form entry?

Thanks

Comment: That's probably a dangerous approach, you may have to reconsider redirecting  users **not based on their input**.

Comment: its more for a search query, so the 123.php would be public anyways - no sensitive info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$page_name=$_POST['usernum'];
$pos=strpos($page_name,"-");
if($pos==true){
$request = substr($page_name,      strpos($page_name, "_") + 1);
//added echo just for visual purposes
header(Location:$request.".php");
}
else{ echo "your user number must be in this form user - user number ";
}
?>
```

Comment: ..and this too! - just had to add quotation marks

Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['usernum'])) {
   $data = $_POST['usernum'];
} else {
   $data = "";
}

$pos = strpos($data, "_");

if (!$pos) {
    echo "No _ found!";
} else {
    $request = substr($data, ++$pos);
    $valid_ids = array("123", "456", "789");

    if (!is_numeric($request) || !in_array($request, $valid_ids)) {
        echo "Invalid user ID!";
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/" + $request + ".php");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: how would it work with an array of inputs eg
123.php, 456.php, 789.php etc? and $data must be $_POST as its linked to the form in the index.php